# How can a user select databricks job id's for job migration through github actions

Tags: github, github-actions, databricks, github-api, aws-databricks

I'm working on a Github actions workflow where databricks jobs are supposed to migrated one environment to higer environment. During this process, we make api call to the databricks workspace and list all available job id's through a python script. From a list of job id's , user has to select one or more job id's that has to be moved to another environment.

To achieve this I've implemented workflow_dispatch event in github actions to select the environment of user's choice.

```yaml
name: Databricks job migration

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

    inputs:

      source_env:
        type: choice
        description: "Select source environment"
        required: true
        options:
        - Dev
        - Test
        - Prod

      target_env:
        description: "Select target environment"
        required: true
        type: choice
        options: ["Dev", "Test", "Prod"]        
jobs:
  databricks_migration:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

       - name: Setup Python
         uses: actions/setup-python@v2
         with:
           python-version: 3.9

       - name: Install dependencies
         run: |
           python -m pip install --upgrade pip
           pip install -r requirements.txt
           pip install requests
    
       - name: Call Databricks API and Extract Job IDs
         id: job_ids
         run: |
           job_ids=$(python .github/workflows/apicall.py)
           echo "::set-output name=job_ids::${job_ids}"
       - name: list Job ID
         id: list_job_id
         run: echo "Selected job ID is ${{ steps.job_ids.outputs.job_ids }}"
        env:
          job_ids: ${{ steps.job_ids.outputs.job_ids }}
        shell: bash
```

after the job id's are fetched, how can I interactively provide user to select one job id that should be migrated to another environment.Please suggest.